# How to change the color of the font in .txt files?

Tags: vim, fonts, colors, neovim

I would like to change the color of the text in .txt files.

More specifically, I would like it to use the same color as it does for comment lines in scripts.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is too vague. There are several ways the colour of the font can be changed, which one is the most applicable depends on how you want Vim to behave.  
I suggest you look into concepts such as "colorscheme" and "syntax highlighting".

Answer (score 1):

As an example,

> ~/.vim/after/syntax/text.vim

```
syntax region textAll start=/\%^/ end=/\%$/
highlight default link textAll Comment
```

Also read [`:help syntax.txt`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html)

Comment: Thanks! Will check that out